# Anti-aliasing on CSS shapes in Firefox

Tags: css, geometry, css-transforms, antialiasing, css-shapes

In Firefox, a triangle has jagged/aliased edges, whether rotated or not.

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eaz9mo6m/2/):

**CSS** (html is just `<div></div>`)

```
div {
    border-top: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-right: 70px solid #777;
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

For shapes that fill their box, you can apply `outline: 1px solid transparent`.

For unrotated shapes, you can simply apply `transform: scale(.999)` (found [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394872/how-do-i-make-a-css-triangle-with-smooth-edges)).

But if I change the last line of CSS to `transform: rotate(90deg) scale(.999)`, aliasing still occurs.

[This bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=767622), filed back in '12 and still marked as "new," is somewhat related, and no attempt at a solution has been made.

Are there any other hacky workarounds to get smooth rotated triangles in Firefox? Getting rid of the hairline down the middle would be a plus.

Comment: Nothing to add, but thanks to you and google I've got rid of the aliasing on my border shape, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the `border-style` of `border-right` to `outset` worked for me on Firefox 32.0.3, also add `height: 0;` and `width: 0;` to remove the hairline.

```css
div {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;      
  border-top: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-right: 70px outset #777;
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin:40px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

If you only want to use the triangle in 'fixed rotated' positions you can take a look at this website:

http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

```css
div {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 70px 10px 0 10px;
  border-color: #777777 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eaz9mo6m/13/)

if you use `border:dotted` it fixes the issue and add `width:0` and `height:0` to remove `1px` space from the middle

```
div {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: dotted solid dotted solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #777777;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 70px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin:40px;
}
```

reference : http://blog.dustinboersma.com/post/45768836072/fixing-osx-firefox-border-triangle-pixelation

Comment: Your fiddle does not make a triangle but a circle for me, i workes with `border-right: 70px outset #777;` though: http://jsfiddle.net/eaz9mo6m/9/

Comment: Very weird, your code seems to work in chrome but is broken for Firefox 32.0.3 (screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/I4nX8Od.png?1), but the code from the referenced blog works..

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work better in Firefox, but Chrome is a bit jagged. If width and height are equal you can control the triangle with transforms pretty easily:

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:0 auto;    
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #777 50%, #fff 50%);
    transform: translate(0,100px) rotate(-135deg) skew(35deg,35deg);
}
```